# add MenuItem to MenuItemTempate on event SPGridView.RowDataBound

Tags: 2010, spgridview

working on custom web part. I included SPGridView to this web part. I know there is an option at the begining define menu items, however I would like to add/delete/modify the menu items dynamically. I would like to do that on event `SPGridView.RowDataBound`. Reason is that here Iam accessing items from various lists. I am able to access the `Menu` from this event hander, however I am not able to add/delete/modify `MenuItem`'s. Is this possible at all? I would not like to just show/hide menu items, I would like to modify them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this,

```
grdAnnouncements.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(grdAnnouncements_RowDataBound);
                BindGrid(dtResultData);
```

You can add a event to rows and then access them using,

```
protected void grdAnnouncements_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
```

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentlegacy/thread/4b66fe0e-4f28-4251-837b-7b83152641fc/)

Comment: well actually i know about this handler, however from here i need to access the menu for the current row item and alter items in menu.